# Importing XML into phpMyAdmin using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, phpmyadmin

I'm stick with trying to import my XML data into phpMyAdmin using SQL but it's producing an empty output
Any Idea?

SQL Query
use geoweb;
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'E:/HTML/XAMPP/htdocs/Volunteer_Projects.xml' 
INTO TABLE projects(`ProjectName`,`Postcode`,`Type`,`Longitude`,`Longitude`);

```
EXAMPLE OF XML FILE
<record>
    <ProjectName>Abersychan Pharmacy</ProjectName>
    <Postcode>NP4 7BQ</Postcode>
    <Type>Health</Type>
    <Longitude>-3.05745263878</Longitude>
    <Latitude>51.72295945</Latitude>
</record>
```

ERROR MESSAGE

use geoweb;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'E:/HTML/XAMPP/htdocs/Volunteer_Projects.xml' INTO TABLE projects(`ProjectName`,`Postcode`,`Type`,`Longitude`,`Longitude`);# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is missing is the ROWS IDENTIFIED BY command.  MySQL assumes an XML file uses the Node  for row and the Name attribute of Field for a column.  By putting the column names in parenthesis, you're defining the columns, but MySql does not know where one row ends and the next one starts.  If you add

```
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<record>'
```

Then it should work.